# Rendering value on an input type=number

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs

I am working with ejs and mongodb/mongoose and what I am trying to do is rendering the page passing the data to an input type="number" on value attribute, but it is not working.

This is the backend part of the code:

```
Produto.findOne({_id: requestedProduct}, function(err, produto){
    res.render("produtosEditar", {
        precoUnitario: produto.precoUnitario
        
    });
});
```

And this is where I am trying to render it:

```
<input class="form-control mid-field" type="number"  min="0" step="any" name="precoUnitario" value="<%= precoUnitario %> ">
```

The value stored in db is higher than 0.
When I change the input type to text, it works, but it doesn't when it is a type="number".

This is an edit data page.

Can you help bros?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `precoUnitario` variable is a valid number. You need to remove the
extra space at the end of `value="<%= precoUnitario %> ">`.

You can see the demo below:

```html
<!-- The extra space at the end of value makes it unvalidate -->
<input class="form-control mid-field" type="number"  min="0" step="any" name="precoUnitario" value="1.5 ">

<!-- This works -->
<input class="form-control mid-field" type="number"  min="0" step="any" name="precoUnitario" value="1.5">
```

Comment: So this sets me from a beginner to a Junior hehehe... thanks bro.